# Set edge/vertex color by group

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I built a network graph with the following dataset:

```
> head(hof)
     username party mentioned_user mentioned_party
7  stbrandner   AfD     gtzfrmming             AfD
11 stbrandner   AfD     joanacotar    fraktionslos
18 stbrandner   AfD     gregorgysi       Die Linke
23 stbrandner   AfD tino_chrupalla             AfD
24 stbrandner   AfD tino_chrupalla             AfD
36 stbrandner   AfD     rbrinkhaus         CDU/CSU

> unique(hof$mentioned_party)
[1] " AfD"                   " fraktionslos"          " Die Linke"            
[4] " CDU/CSU"               " SPD"                   " FDP"                  
[7] " Bündnis 90/Die Grünen"
> unique(hof$party)
[1] " AfD"                   " CDU/CSU"               " FDP"                  
[4] " fraktionslos"          " Bündnis 90/Die Grünen" " Die Linke"            
[7] " SPD"
```

I defined a set of colors and create a PNG-File with the graph and also a visIGraph Graph:

```
colors <-  c("#33CCFF","white","purple","black", "red", "yellow", "#00FF33")
mygraph3 <- graph.data.frame(hof, directed = TRUE) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "color", value = colors[match(hof$party, unique(hof$party))]) %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "color", value = colors[match(hof$party, unique(hof$party))])
png("who_receives_hof.png", 1000, 1000)
plot(mygraph3,
     vertex.label = NA,
     vertex.size = 1,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
)
dev.off()
saveWidget(visIgraph(mygraph3), file = "who_receives_hof.html")
```

Every vertex/edge of the column "party" should have a specific color, e.g. "AfD" -> #33CCFF; "fraktionslos" -> "white", ...

Somehow my match function doesn't work correctly, so the color is not always correct.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Try `>mygraph3` and check if this is the graph you want to build.